# Failure trying to switch between two embedded Elm apps in the same node

Tags: elm

I am trying to dynamically switch between Elm apps based on user input.

Both apps are transpiled in js files via `elm make` (Eg : Foo.js exposing module Foo and Bar.js exposing module Bar)

Two buttons run the usual "Elm.[Foo|Bar].init(node:document.querySelector('main')" so that in theory I could switch between rendering either of the apps.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="[..]/foo.js"></script>
  <script src="[..]/bar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main></main>

  <input value="Foo" type="button" name="Foo" onclick="Elm.Foo.init({node:document.querySelector('main')});">
  <input value="Bar" type="button" name="Bar" onclick="Elm.Bar.init({node:document.querySelector('main')});">
</body>
</html>
```

To be clear, both apps should alternate in taking over the  element.

When I hit either of the buttons for the first time, the app renders correctly, but a second click produces the following error

```
Error: What node should I take over? In JavaScript I need something like:

    Elm.Main.init({
        node: document.getElementById("elm-node")
    })

You need to do this with any Browser.sandbox or Browser.element program.
```

And indeed the  element is somehow deleted upon rendering the first app.

I could not find any mention of this behaviour in the docs and I would like to know if it is possible to prevent this from happening in any way, and if it is expected behaviour.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the first `Elm` module will replace the `<main>` tag with the elm view so the next `Elm` module cannot find that `<main>` tag anymore. You can check on the dev tool.

My solution: Wrap your views with the `main` tag like this.

> Foo.elm

```
view model =
  node "main" 
    []
    [ div [] [ text "foo foo foo" ] ]
```

> Bar.elm

```
view model =
  node "main" 
    []
    [ div [] [ text "bar bar bar" ] ]
```

So It can find and replace the `<main>` tag for the second button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I must admit I do not like the workaround much, as it would "couple" any elm app to this particular exercise, while I was looking for a generic way to embed applications as components.

I am almost afraid to ask, but what would be the disadvantages of embedding elm apps in iframes? They have a bad reputation but the literature I have seen against this element in HTML5 does not have solid arguments, so far